# Подключение pip

Tags: python, pycharm

Ребят, подскажите как в pycharm установить pip, для подключения модулей

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Пакетный менеджер уже установлен в PyCharm в разделе Settings - Project: - Project Interpreter, нажми там плюсик и введи остальные пакеты или скачай pip, если отсутствует

Comment: @DissMind, тогда [ответ отметьте как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (галочка под слева от ответа)